# Open verification code sent in mail box then copy this code and paste it into verification code field in selenium testing

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am new to selenium web testing i have automated a Sign-In process for a web base application. now making it for Sign Up process i am stuck at a point where a verification code is sent to a mail address and then i have to copy that into my verification code field and proceed further

As i have searched so far i came to know about the mailosaur server but unable to copy that email verification code into my automated web browser. i also searched for the tutorials but unable to find any useful resource. also i want to generate random emails that part is also not getting in my mind.

As i am new to selenium so it is requested to please provide detail answer so i can understand it better, Thanks in advance, working on Intellij, Mavaen (Java)

Answer (score 0):

You can use mailinator.com. No need to register or create a mail box. In your app just enter email with made up name @mailinator.com (asad1@mailinator.com, asadXY@mailinator.com, whatever).

To collect confirmation link (double opt in) I'm using this:

```
public class Mailinator {
    public WebDriver driver;
    public Mailinator(WebDriver driver) {this.driver = driver;}
    public String urlMailinator = "https://www.mailinator.com/"; 
    public WebDriverWait waitSec(WebDriver driver, int sec) {return new WebDriverWait(driver, sec);}
    public static String doubleOptInLink = null;
    public String getDoubleOptInLink() {return doubleOptInLink;}
    public void setDoubleOptInLink (String doubleOptInLink) {Mailinator.doubleOptInLink = doubleOptInLink;} 

    public void collectDoubleOptInLink(String userEmail, int expectedNumberOfDeliveredEmails) throws InterruptedException {
        driver.get(urlMailinator);                  
        WebElement fldInbox = waitSec(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("inboxfield")));
        fldInbox.sendKeys(userEmail);
        WebElement btnGo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/section[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/span/button"));
        btnGo.click();
        waitSec(driver, 600).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBe((By.xpath("//*[@id=\"inboxpane\"]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr")), expectedNumberOfDeliveredEmails));
        WebElement lastMailLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"inboxpane\"]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr"));
        lastMailLink.click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("msg_body")));
        setDoubleOptInLink(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"intro\"]/tbody/tr/td/a")).getAttribute("href"));
    }
}
```

In my scenario:

1. register to webapp with new made up email, confirmation email is send
2. using `collectDoubleOptInLink(email, 1);` is the confirmation link set as `doubleOptInLink`
3. calling another method to go to the confirmation link with `getDoubleOptInLink();`

Sure you will need change what string comes to `setDoubleOptInLink()`;
In specific cases don't forget to `setDoubleOptInLink(null);`.